# What is worker , dyno and zero-downtime deploys in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn, webrick, puma

These three terms have given a lot of importance in understanding different app server in heroku tutorials but I can't understand the purpose and definition of these three terms.
Can anybody have info about that. Kindly share
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Heroku reference guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/reference#heroku-architecture) has a lot of information on all of this, and lots more, but in answer to your question;

- A dyno is effectively a small virtual server instance set up to run one app (it's behind an invisible load balancer, so you can have any number of them running side-by-side). You don't need to worry about the server admin side of things, as it just takes your source code from a Git push and runs it.
- A worker is a type of dyno, usually designed to process tasks in the background (in contrast to a web dyno, which just serves web pages. For example, Rails has ActiveJob, which plugs into something like Resque or Sidekiq, completes tasks which would slow down the web interface if it has to complete them, like sending e-mails, or geocoding addresses.
- Zero-downtime deploys is really marketing speak for "if you push your code, it will wait until the new version is up and running before swapping the web interface to use it". It means you don't need to do anything, and your web app won't go offline while it is switched over to.